# Can sunlight cause my dog's fur to lighten

Tags: dogs

I have an almost 3 years old part choc lab/german shorthair.  Her hair had been a beautiful dark choc brown until the past year where I've noticed there are parts on her back changing to a very light, almost tan color.  She is outside a lot so I'm not sure if the sun is doing this.  The rest of her fur is still choc brown.  She's very healthy, active and eats well.

Comment: Dupe of "Is it normal for my dog's coat to change color", perhaps?

Comment: Of course it can, just like it can fade any other pigment in the world.